# .net and Java migration equivalent table

Tags: c#, java, .net

I see this interested migration table from Java and C#:

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html#fileio

I need something like this but from .net framework and Java.

I searched on internet but I don't have found a good comparison.

Where I can find  a very good useful migration equivalent comparation of .net and Java ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN has a page with a variety of information including tables about half-way down that show C#/.NET equivalents to commonly used Java packages.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973842.aspx

Is this enough or is there anything more specific that you need?

Comment: I have aready find this, but I like to see semething more complete if there is.

Comment: Perhaps it's best to focus on a single direction then.  Are you migrating from .NET to Java, or Java to .NET?  Furthermore, specifying a platform would help as well: JSP/ASP.NET? JavaFX/Silverlight? Desktop executable?  Console application?

Comment: I need to migrate from .net to Java. only Desktop applications (no web or mobile) only client database application. It is not easy especially for me that I have 0 experience with Java.

Comment: You need more experience with Java if you are to migrate your existing application to it.